# ArrayList get all the elements

Tags: java, arraylist

In this function, once my if statement becomes true, it returns a value and it "kicks" me out of the function. I'm trying to get the rest of the elements of the arrayList, so i know which ones i'm not going to access it. My question is, how can i get the rest of the elements from the array?

```
For(Node a:state.children)
{
    state.value = Math.max(state.value,min_value(a, alpha, beta));
    alpha = Math.max(alpha,state.value);
    if(beta <=alpha)
    {
        System.out.println("The elements that are going to be skipped are: " + a.label);
        return state.value;
    }
}
```

How can I make a copy of the last elements of the array that are not going to be used because of the return statement

Comment: what you want as result?

Comment: That's the concept of `return` statement: stop the execution on the method when calling the `return`. So, as @chintan posted, what's your expected result?

Comment: so isn't there a way or a pointer that points to the last elements?

Comment: ok. You can try this. put the return statement out side the if condition. then try.I think it's work. You got my point?

Comment: It would be better if you at least post your method signature and explain what it should to.

Comment: like:- for(...){  if(...){ } return ;}

Comment: You understand? or I put sample code.

Comment: in c++ i would create make a second arrayList that is exactly like this one(copy) and have a pointer to the last element that was used before return

Comment: sample code if you don't mind @chintan

Comment: @JohnKemp this is not C++, this is Java. Please **update your question** adding the relevant code so people can understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another ArrayList which will hold the unskipped values.
To do that, add an else block to the existing if block. In the else block add the element to the temp ArrayList. Iterate through the temp ArrayList to get the unskipped values.

```
ArrayList<Node> tempList = new ArrayList<Node>();
For(Node a:state.children)
{
    state.value = Math.max(state.value,min_value(a, alpha, beta));
    alpha = Math.max(alpha,state.value);
    if(beta <=alpha)
    {
        System.out.println("The elements that are going to be skipped are: " + a.label);
    } else {
        tempList.add(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please vote up for my post if it was helpful.

Comment: but that doesn't let me copy the last elements

Comment: The tempList will hold all elements which were not skipped, the position of the element being irrelevant.

Comment: how do i know exactly where did it stop at, because i want to get the elemtns from the location where it stopped until the end of the arrayList

Comment: Use an iterator instead of what you are doing now.
By using an iterator while iterating you will know where the processing stopped, from there on you can use the same iterator reference to iterate through the remaining elements.

Comment: thank you. sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to return from the function, dont have the return statement inside the if. If you need to use it outside, store them in a collection and use it

Comment: i need to break there tho. i was following the alpha beta pruning algorithm...and there's a break

Comment: `break` will get you out of the loop. `continue` will skip the remaining part within the iteration of loop and goes to next iteration. `return` will exit out of the function. which one you want?